# Which BBCode parsers have been tested for XSS vulnerabilities

Tags: php, security, xss, bbcode

I'm currently trying to switch from an HTML wysiwyg editor to a BBCode one, to reduce the risk of XSS vulnerabilities on a website where users can write content. Verifying HTML server-side was my first idea (for example with HTML purifier), but this has been rejected (not my decision).

So now I'm searching for a PHP BBCode parser (which would output HTML) that would be secure. So far I've seen jBBCode and NBBC. NBBC claims to be secure in their documentation, while jBBCode says nothing about the problem.

What resources could I use to get a better idea of which implementation is the most secure? Are there independent reviews, hacker contests, etc, that could give more confidence in one or another library? (I'm open to other implementation suggestions by the way).

Comment: AnyBBcodeParser -> HTMLPurifier is the way to go

Comment: OK, thanks for the tip. In this case I don't see the point in using BBCode at all ; but as I said it's not my decision, so that's what I'll do: send BBCode to the server, and return "purified" HTML (converted from the BBCode) to viewers.